# How we can find the symmetric group with least $n$ whose subgroup of it is isomorphic to $G$?

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-isomorphism

By Cayley's Theorem any group $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$ for $n = |G|$ (since we can think of group actions as permutations of the group elements). And I am asking if there is a general way of calculating the least $n \le |G|$ with such property.

Let me illustrate what I mean by an example: We know that $D_3$ is isomorphic to $S_3$. But by Cayley's Theorem we also know that $D_3$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_6$ (since every group action is a permutation of $3\cdot2 = 6$ elements). In this case least such $n \le |G|$ is $3$. I am asking for a general way of calculating the $n$ for an arbitrary group $G$.

Comment: This is an open question and is thought to be hard in general. The answer is known in many cases, such as if $G$ is abelian. The least $n$ is often called the *minimal degree* or *minimal degree of a faithful permutation representation* of $G$. I recommend *Minimal Faithful Permutation Representations of Finite Groups* by Johnson as a decent starting point for reading about this, but there has been a lot written since then.

Comment: Thanks for reading advice, i will check it out. Also if this is an open question, i think this post must be closed?

Comment: @robert-chamberlain What about converting your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an open question and is thought to be hard in general.

While improving my answer I found [this answer on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/a/16863/59158) to the same question, which pretty much covers what I'm going to say.

The answer is known in many cases, such as if $G$ is abelian. The least $n$ is often called the *minimal degree* or *minimal degree of a faithful permutation representation* of $G$. The minimal degree of $G$ is denoted $\mu(G)$.

I recommend *Minimal Faithful Permutation Representations of Finite Groups* by Johnson as a decent starting point for reading about this, but there has been a lot written since then.

---

**Some Results:**

*Abelian Groups (Johnson)*

Let $G=\prod_{i=1}^kC_{p_i^{e_i}}$ where $p_i$ is prime and $e_i\in\mathbb{N}$ for each $i$. Then $\mu(G)=\sum_{i=1}^kp_i^{e_i}$.

*Incompressible Groups (Johnson)*

We call $G$ incompressible if $\mu(G)=|G|$. These are fully classified by Johnson. A group $G$ is incompressible if and only if $G$ is one of the following:

- Klein $4$-group, $C_2\times C_2$.
- Cyclic of prime power order.
- Generalised quaternion $2$-group.

*Simple Groups*

If $G$ is simple then any faithful permutation representation of $G$ is equivalent to the action of $G$ on the right cosets of a largest subgroup of $G$. These are known for all simple $G$, but finding a comprehensive list turns out to be quite challenging and some over the years have contained errors. The linked MO question gives some papers with good lists. I also refer to *The use of permutation representations in structural computations in
large finite matrix groups* by *Cannon, Holt, Unger* for an up to date list.

*Direct Products*

It's not hard to show that $\mu(G\times H)\le\mu(G)+\mu(H)$, but sometimes this equality holds. The most general results I can find are:

- (Johnson) If $G=\prod_{i=1}^kS_i$ where each $S_i$ is simple then $\mu(G)=\sum_{i=1}^k\mu(S_i)$
- (Becker) If $G$ and $H$ each have central socle (this includes nilpotent groups) then $\mu(G\times H)=\mu(G)+\mu(H)$.

The paper by Becker is called *The minimal degree of permutation representations of finite groups*.