# Finding the minimal $n$ such that $C_{12}$ is a subgroup of $S_{n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, cyclic-groups, permutation-cycles

I guess that there is no general solution for $C_{k}$ and unfortunately, I couldn't find a specific one for $C_{12}$.
Cayley's theorem claims that such $n$ exists, and Lagrange's theorem claims that $n \geq 4$; Don't know what to do next; If I'm not mistaken, $C_{12}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_{12}}$ but I don't know how it may help.

Comment: You need an element of order $12$ in your $S_n$. There are different ways of achieving that. For instance, $S_{12}$ has a cycle of length (and therefore order) 12. Can you do better?

Comment: Oh, well... Then $S_{7}$ may be represented as 4+3, so element order is 12 and the answer is $S_{7}$, right?

Comment: You need to show that $S_6$ is impossible. But other than that, yeah.

Comment: Thanks a lot! it really helped

Comment: See http://oeis.org/A008475

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3362305/how-we-can-find-the-symmetric-group-with-least-n-whose-subgroup-of-it-is-isomo?rq=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *minimal permutation degree* $d(G)$ of a finite group $G$ is the least integer $d$ such that $G$ can be embedded into $S_d$.
Let $G\cong C_{p_1^{e_1}}\times \cdots \times C_{p_r^{e_r}}$. Then we have

$$
d(G)=\sum_{i=1}^r p_i^{e_i}.
$$

For a proof see for example [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.1668). Since $12=2^2\cdot 3$, we have $$
d(C_{12})=2^2+3=7.
$$